# How would %privilege time of sqlsvr instance indicate cpu consumption of other processes?

Tags: sql-server, cpu, perfmon

I am looking at msdn doc to monitor cpu.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-issues#step-1-verify-that-sql-server-is-causing-high-cpu-usage

It says I need to capture the %user time and %privileged time for sqlsvr instance.

Then it goes to say high %user time means sqlsvr is keeping cpu busy. Where as high %privileges time means other processes or anti-virus is keeping the cpu busy.

My question is - how would %privilege time of sqvsvr instance indicate cpu consumption of other processes?

Answer (score 3):

Privileged time is when a process thread is running in the kernel.  All of the SQL Server code, like most applications, runs in user-mode, not kernel mode.

It's not other processes, but drivers or products that insert themselves into the storage [driver stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/driver-stacks) (particularly anti-virus or storage solution [filter drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/performance-consistency-issues-filter-drivers-modules#filter-drivers)) that are the common cause of high privileged time.

Comment: Similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/performance-consistency-issues-filter-drivers-modules?

Comment: Yes.  I've added that link to the answer.

Comment: But these metrics tell you how much of cpu time % sqlsvr has taken. It doesn't tell you whether there is cpu pressure? I think cpu pressure is when the processor is heavily used across all services on the computer?